# Spring & neo4j: Previous relationships are deleted when adding new ones

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Here is my User class:

```java
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Property
    private String name;

    @Property
    private String email;

    @Property
    private String password;

    @Property
    private String photoLink;

    @Property
    private Integer age;

    @Property
    private Country country;

    @Property
    private Gender gender;

    @Property
    private String about;

    @Property
    private boolean online;

    private Collection<UserHasLanguage> hasLanguage;

    @Relationship(type="HAS_ROLE", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    @Relationship(type="HAS_IN_FRIENDLIST", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<User> friendList;

    @Relationship(type="HAS_IN_BLACKLIST", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<User> blackList;
```

So I want users to have one-side relationships HAS_IN_FRIENDLIST to other users.
At the service level I have a method for adding friends to user:

```java
public void addToFriendList (User whoAdds, User whoIsAdded)
        throws UserNotFoundException{
    if (whoIsAdded == null)
        throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found");
    Collection<User> friendList = whoAdds.getFriendList();
    if (friendList == null)
        friendList = new HashSet<>();
    friendList.add(whoIsAdded);
    whoAdds.setFriendList(friendList);
    userRepository.save(whoAdds);
}
```

However, when I use this method, some previous relationships "HAS_IN_FRIENDLIST" of this user are removed. 
I have noticed, that whoAdds.getFriendList() method always returns only 1 User.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you use the `@Relationship(type="HAS_IN_FRIENDLIST", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
` annotation also on the setter?

Comment: And please specify a version of SDN you are using.

Comment: @frant.hartm Thank you. I tried but result is the same. I found out that when I load user from database, friendlist always consists only of one user even if he has many relationships. So now I am trying to understand why it's happening.
I don't know how to find version of sdn - In pom.xml I just specified this: 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: And your spring boot version is?

Comment: It is 1.5.1.RELEASE

Comment: Does friendList have a setter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this, but my understanding is that Collection isn't supported. For a list, you must use one of these (as specified [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference:annotating-entities:relationship))

java.util.Vector

java.util.List, backed by a java.util.ArrayList

java.util.SortedSet, backed by a java.util.TreeSet

java.util.Set, backed by a java.util.HashSet

Arrays

So change `Collection<User>` to `Set<User>`